# NGUI dynamic font texture became solid rectanges at some Android devices

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, ngui

My game is developed by Unity 4.6 and NGUI, the fonts are dynamic fonts to support Asian characters, but at **some** Android devices the fonts failed to display properly, characters became solid blocks.

[image: font display wired in game]

I have tried to render the font texture, the UIFont.texture is defined as

`public Texture2D texture
    {
        get
        {
            if (mReplacement != null) return mReplacement.texture;
            Material mat = material;
            return (mat != null) ? mat.mainTexture as Texture2D : null;
        }
    }`

and property `material` is `mDynamicFont.material`, the rendering result is a **solid black rectangle**.

[image: dynamic font texture]

Font texture size is 512x1024, and the uv of CharacterInfo is valid, so I dont know why font texture became so wired and how to fix it.

PS: the font works perfect at first scene, and stop to work when some new scenes  are loaded, maybe some resources release APIs are called.

Comment: you could try it with another font file and see if that might be the cause.

Comment: I don't know what exactly happens, but I'd suggest you investigate on the compatibility of the shader used to render the font on the specific Android device. You could try different shaders for this rendering. Besides, does your specific Android device support the font you're trying to render?

Comment: The device works at first scene, and don't at some other scenes, it seems not the font's fault, I have changed the font, but the problem remains. I don't know what might invalid the font's textures or shaders.

Comment: Here comes the new situation, when the font's displaying weirdly, I enlarge the font texture by call `RequestCharactersInTexture`, when the texture size changed, the texture becomes normal now. still don't know why and how to fix it.